# How to fetch an remote API with svelte?

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, svelte-component

I am fetching a quote from an API and the fetching seems to work, because the first `console.log` is being called correctly, but second is not. The content is a field in the `json` object from the API.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    let non = [];


    onMount(async function() {
        const res = await fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
        const json = await res.json();
        non.push(json);
        console.log(non);
    });

</script>

<div>
   {#each non as {content}}
   <p>{content}{console.log(content)}</p>
   {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: Is a console.log really allowed in a Svelte template? Cool if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments, using array
>   methods like `push` and `splice` won't automatically cause updates.

In yor example, if you replace `non.push(json)` with `non = [json]` it seems to [work](https://svelte.dev/repl/fc4706126df94732be33876e560cdc99?version=3.9.1).

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

Answer (score 4):

> Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments. (Source: [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#2_Assignments_are_reactive))

So if you want to push more quotes into `non`, you have to do so using `non = [...non, json];`

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    let non = [];
    let gettingQuote = false;

    onMount(() => {
        getRandomQuote();
    });

    async function getRandomQuote() {
        gettingQuote = true;
        const res = await fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
        const json = await res.json();
        non = [...non, json];
        gettingQuote = false;
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each non as {author, content}}
        <p>{content} - {author}</p>
    {/each}
    <button on:click={getRandomQuote} disabled={gettingQuote}>Get Quote</button>
    {#if gettingQuote}
        <span>Getting Quote...</span>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Here is a working [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/20351b70113a42a8a44c862743e48a28?version=3.9.1).